# php native query to codeigniter query

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm confuse about this. How well I be able to make this query into the CodeIgniter model query? Here's my php native query below.

```
$query = "SELECT
              seminars.id,
              seminars.thumb,
              seminars_category.category,
              seminars_category.url,
              seminars_category.date,
              seminars_category.abvr
              FROM
              seminars
              INNER JOIN seminars_category ON seminars_category.id = seminars.category
              WHERE seminars.id = 1 OR seminars.id = 7 OR seminars.id = 12 OR seminars.id = 20
              OR seminars.id = 24 OR seminars.id = 29 OR seminars.id= 77 OR seminars.id = 84 OR seminars.id = 103 
              OR seminars.id = 157 OR seminars.id = 187 OR seminars.id = 234 OR seminars.id =  241 OR seminars.id = 308 OR seminars.id = 314 OR seminars.id = 390
              OR seminars.id = 407 OR seminars.id = 414 OR seminars.id = 429 OR seminars.id = 455 OR seminars.id = 462 OR seminars.id = 511 OR seminars.id = 537 OR seminars.id = 573
              OR seminars.id = 591 OR seminars.id = 641
              ORDER BY seminars_category.date DESC
              "
              ;
    $res = mysql_query($query);
```

I want this to put in

```
public function getAllActivities(){
 
}
```

And in my controller is here

```
 $this->data['activities'] = $this->am->getAllActivities();
```

Can someone help me from php native query to CodeIgniter?

Thanks.

Comment: You have all you need here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: yes i know . its all in the user guide

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('seminars.id, 
            seminars.thumb, 
            seminars_category.category,
            seminars_category.url,
            seminars_category.date,
            seminars_category.abvr');
        $this->db->join('seminars_category', 'seminars_category.id = seminars.category', 'inner');
        //use a loop here for better implementation of the where-clause
        $this->db->where('seminars.id  =', 1);
        $this->db->or_where('seminars.id  =', 7); 
        $this->db->or_where('seminars.id  =', 12);
        $this->db->order_by('seminars_category.date', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

its not tested and just written with the documentation of CI. you can for sure use DRY and implement a loop for there where-clause.

hope it works or give you at least an idea how it could work

Comment: you should debug it using this: echo $this->db->last_query; and you will get the SQL for that.

Comment: ive tried the code but it goes this to my error Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: i already added it to the controller and to views to display the data